# Fall back to running out of the original dex file

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to retrieve data from firebase database and display it Recycler view.App retrieves data from the database and display in a recyclerview
The app runs nicely without erros but the activity is blank
it is not showing any data in recycler view

error:Fall back to running out of the original dex file

logcat message

```
12-01 00:48:17.675 20068-20068/com.smartinfo.techguy.smartinfodesk W/ActionBarDrawerToggle: DrawerToggle may not show up because NavigationIcon is not visible. You may need to call actionbar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
12-01 00:48:17.680 20068-20482/com.smartinfo.techguy.smartinfodesk W/zygote64: Unsupported class loader
12-01 00:48:17.682 20068-20482/com.smartinfo.techguy.smartinfodesk W/zygote64: Skipping duplicate class check due to unsupported classloader
miui_dex2oat:　OatFile: /data/user_de/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/0000002a/oat/arm64/DynamiteLoader.odex Compiler-Filter = speed
12-01 00:48:17.684 20068-20482/com.smartinfo.techguy.smartinfodesk I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.firebase_database:4 and remote module com.google.android.gms.firebase_database:6
Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.firebase_database, version >= 6
12-01 00:48:17.693 20068-20089/com.smartinfo.techguy.smartinfodesk V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 1068272741
12-01 00:48:17.698 20068-20089/com.smartinfo.techguy.smartinfodesk D/FA: Logging event (FE): screen_view(_vs), Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto, firebase_previous_class(_pc)=Academic, firebase_previous_id(_pi)=8271408059740876105, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=Contact, firebase_screen_id(_si)=8271408059740876106}]
12-01 00:48:17.716 20068-20482/com.smartinfo.techguy.smartinfodesk W/zygote64: Unsupported class loader
12-01 00:48:17.717 20068-20482/com.smartinfo.techguy.smartinfodesk W/zygote64: miui_dex2oat: oat file of /data/user_de/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/0000002c/DynamiteModulesC.apk is not exists
12-01 00:48:17.773 20068-20482/com.smartinfo.techguy.smartinfodesk W/zygote64: miui_dex2oat: /data/user_de/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/0000002c/DynamiteModulesC.apk: Fall back to running out of the original dex file.
12-01 00:48:17.820 20068-20073/com.smartinfo.techguy.smartinfodesk I/zygote64: Compiler allocated 4MB to compile void android.view.View.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int, int)
12-01 00:48:17.935 20068-20073/com.smartinfo.techguy.smartinfodesk   I/zygote64: Do full code cache collection, code=214KB, data=172KB
12-01 00:48:17.936 20068-20073/com.smartinfo.techguy.smartinfodesk I/zygote64: After code cache collection, code=186KB, data=120KB
12-01 00:48:22.737 20068-20089/com.smartinfo.techguy.smartinfodesk V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
```

My main class

```
 DatabaseReference dref;
 Bundle bundle;
 RecyclerView Rview;
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_contact);
     //DATABASE INSTANCE INITILIZE
    dref= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Contact");
    dref.keepSynced(true);
 /* Program Logic starts here the firestore with
    The recyclerview
 */
       Rview=(RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recycle);
       Rview.setHasFixedSize(true);
       Rview.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
       }

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<RecyclerInput,RecycleViewHolder>firebaseRecyclerAdapter=new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter
            <RecyclerInput, RecycleViewHolder>
            (RecyclerInput.class,R.layout.recycle_row,RecycleViewHolder.class,dref) {
        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(RecycleViewHolder viewHolder, RecyclerInput model, int position)
        {
            viewHolder.setName(model.getName());
            viewHolder.setPaper(model.getPaper());
            viewHolder.setNumber(model.getNumber());

        }
    };
    Rview.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);

    }

public static class RecycleViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
{
    View mview;
    public RecycleViewHolder(View itemView)
    {
            super(itemView);
            mview=itemView;
    }

    public void setName(String name)
    {
        TextView Name=(TextView)mview.findViewById(R.id.contactName);
        Name.setText(name);
    }

    public void setNumber(String number)
    {
        TextView Number=(TextView)mview.findViewById(R.id.contactNo);
        Number.setText(number);
    }
    public void setPaper(String paper)
    {
        TextView Pname =(TextView)mview.findViewById(R.id.contactPaper);
        Pname.setText(paper);

    }

}


//Toggle button Clickable code

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{

    if(mToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item))
    {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: When you override a method and still call the base-class' method, you should call the base class method first.  In your onOptionsItemSelected you're possibly skipping over important code.  I don't know if this is your problem or not, but it strikes me as dangerous code atm.

Comment: @DanRayson That's FAR from absolutely the case.  For example, an override could transform some data before passing it to the base method.  That's at best a style rule for the common case, and will just about never be the cause of an error.  In this case his code looks correct-  he doesn't want the default behavior unless that function returns false.

Comment: Something  (and it may be the google play services itself) is playing games with loading code dynamially and failing.  Hence the warnings about unsupported class loader.  I'd manually update the Google Play Services on your device and see if that helps.  Also make sure you're using an up to date version of all those libraries.

Comment: @GabeSechan I was thinking in terms of SO`L`ID, and the way in which I program.  i.e I would never replace derived code with new, nor modify the parameters that are passed to it.  I would create a new class, as it is "doing something different".  Having said that, your example blew my theory out of the water, I stand completely and humbly corrected.  If the base class' functionality is designed in such a way that it doesn't have to be run, and/or can handle a change to its usual input parameters, then yes, his code is perfectly valid.  I still wouldn't make the assumption that this is the case

Comment: @GabeSechan Having actually read the question twice now, I can see that my argument was completely invalid anyway - His error is to do with a classloader being invalid...  Nothing to do with what I said.

Comment: Can you please send me the corrected code for the above class